# ActiveRecord::Relation joins with more conditions than just the foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, arel

Is there any way to specify more than one conditions for a left outer join using ActiveRecord::Relation?

Take the following SQL statement for example. How can anyone rewrite this using ActiveRecord::Relation objects?

```
SELECT `texts`.*, `text_translations`.translation FROM `texts` LEFT OUTER JOIN `text_translations` ON `text_translations`.`id` = `texts`.`id` AND `text_translations`.`locale` = 'en'
```

Is there any way to do this under ActiveRecord 3.0.3+?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

first you should consider to use rails/activerecord conform relations. This means the foreign key in the text_translations table should be called text_id

Create your models and associations like this:

```
class Text < ActiveRecord::Base

  # all possible translations!
  has_many :text_translations

  scope :with_translation_for, lambda { |lang| {
    :select     => "texts.*, tt.translation",
    :joins      => "LEFT OUTER JOIN text_translations AS tt ON tt.text_id = texts.id AND tt.locale = #{ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize(lang)}"
  }}


  # return nil if translation hasn't been loaded, otherwise you get a nasty NoMethod exception
  def translation
    read_attribute(:translation)
  end

end
```

and

```
class TextTranslation < ActiveRecord::Base
  # every translation belongs to a text
  belongs_to :text

  # define a scope for the language
  scope :language, lambda { |lang| where(['locale = ?', lang]) }

end
```

How to use:

```
texts = Text.with_translation_for('en')
texts.each do |c_text|
    unless c_text.translation.nil?
        puts c_text.translation
    else
        puts "No translation available!"
    end
end
```

Now to the pro and cons, the way using LEFT OUTER join will load you *all* texts even if there isn't a translation for a text in the desired language. The con is that you won't get the "TextTranslation" model object.

Anotherway is to load only the text which have the desired translation. You can do it like:

```
texts = Text.includes(:text_translations).where(:text_translations => {:locale => 'en'})
```

now `texts[i].text_translations` will return an array with all TextTranslations model object for this text matching the locale 'en'. But texts without a translation in the locale "en" won't show up.

**Edit**

Connected to your comment:

The problem about using `.join(:tablename)` on a relation is that, it will result in an INNER JOIN so this is not an option. You have to explicitly declare the LEFT join. Another thing is that if you use something like `Text.includes(:text_translations).where(['text_translations.locale = ?', 'en'])` the condition will be applied to the SQL query as whole and not on the possible LEFT join itself. What you actually can do is to declare associations like

```
has_many :english_translations, :class_name => 'TextTranslation', :conditions => ['locale = ?', 'en']
```

This way you can manage to load only english translations by eager loading (without any joins at all):

```
Text.includes(:english_translations).all
```

Checkt this out:

- [Ruby On Rails Guide about Joining Tables](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables)
- [ActiveRecord Association Docs, Search for LEFT OUTER JOIN](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html)

Comment: first of all thanks for your insights but the starting question was how to append more than one conditions on a left outer join using Relation and thus refrain from hardcoding _:joins => "LEFT OUTER JOIN text_translations AS tt ON tt.text_id = texts.id AND tt.locale = #{ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize(lang)}"_ in the code.

Comment: have a look at my edit, I hope this will answer your question

Comment: there's a way to declare a left outer join (using meta_where) by __.joins(:translations.outer)__. Anyways, I think that most people would just hardcode this so thanks for your input.